# Timer for javascript button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web

The below code generates a json string on the click of some buttons.

```
<div id="btnStudios" >
    <button type="button" id="01" value="warner" class="btn btn-default">Warner</button>
    <button type="button" id="02" value="tf1" class="btn btn-default">TF1</button>
    <button type="button" id="03" value="gaumont" class="btn btn-default">Gaumont</button>
    <button type="button" id="04" value="pathe" class="btn btn-default">Pathe</button>
    <button type="button" id="05" value="studiocanal" class="btn btn-default">StudioCanal</button>
    <button type="button" id="06" value="francetv" class="btn btn-default">FranceTV</button>
    <button type="button" id="07" value="m6snd" class="btn btn-default">M6SND</button>
</div>


var output = $(".btn").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
        var output = {
            Studios: $('#btnStudios button.active').map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
    }).get(),
};

if (!output.Studios.length) {
    output.Studios = $('#btnStudios button').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get()
$('.list').html(JSON.stringify(output));
});
```

Basically what i am looking for is a timer which refreshes for 1 second everytime a button is clicked and then generates the json string based on the button selection.
I used the `setInterval()` function but that did not help.

How would i go about this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I used the setInterval() function but that did not help"* What did that attempt look like? Although from your problem description, I'd've thought `setTimeout` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking. But if you want to do something one second after the click, you should look into [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), which performs an action after n milliseconds. As opposed to setInterval, which repeats it every n milliseconds.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I enclosed the above javascript into a sigle variable x looked like setTimeout(x,1000). The error i get is SyntaxError: missing ] after element list.

Comment: I get the same error when I try setTimeout (($('.list').html(JSON.stringify(output))),1000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't *fully* understand your question.

However, based on the code, I assume you want to show a JSON-string based on which buttons have the **.active** class?

Your code contained syntax errors.

I created a quick [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7cy5h8ey/) with what I think you wanted.

However, I have made no use of `setTimeout` since I couldn't come up with valid use case.

Feel free to provide us with more info and I'll improve my answer!

**EDIT:**

Okay, so you want to wait **1sec** after the click.
I updated the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tz9zu55g/1/).

**EDIT²:**

I'd also use `clearTimeout` so clicks that happened *while* you are already waiting 1 sec are ignored.
As seen in [this JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tz9zu55g/2/).

Comment: Yes pretty much. I have just updated the jsfiddle a little. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7cy5h8ey/4/)  I want a delay of 1 second on the click of every button before the whole JSON string is generated. Is this better?

Comment: Great! But the delay i am looking for is in the generation of the whole JSON string and not the individual objects. For example I click a button the timer waits for 1 second and then generates the string. Now if I select 3 buttons the system generates the JSON string 1 second after the 3rd button is selected. So the timer refreshes for 1 second after every button click.